# RegexOptions.Multiline seems to ignore \n

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to search a string using Regex.  Here's what the string looks like in the Text Visualizer:

```
0 -12.67 Td
/Helv 14 Tf
(Source: ABC / XYZA) Tj
0 -15.624 Td
(Job Source No.: GRQX ID 27299) Tj
0 -15.624 Td
```

When I view the value by hovering on it:

```
0 -12.67 Td\n/Helv 14 Tf\n(Source: ABC / XYZA) Tj\n0 -15.624 Td\n(Job Source No.: GRQX ID 27299) Tj\n0 -15.624 Td
```

I'm using `Regex.Matches()` with the following pattern and `RegexOptions.Multiline`:

```
^(?<=[(]).+(?=[)])
```

This returns no matches.  When I omit the caret, like this:

```
(?<=[(]).+(?=[)])
```

then `Regex.Matches()` returns both matches:

```
Source: ABC / XYZA
Job Source No.: GRQX ID 27299
```

How can I match on the first character in a line?

Comment: That's because you have an anchor followed by a look behind.  It would work if you put the anchor in the look behind `(?<=^[(]).+(?=[)])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lookbehind in a regex pattern checks the characters to the left of the current position, so in your pattern `^(?<=[(])` requires a `(` to be before the `^` (the start of a line). Before a start of a line, there is either nothing (at the start of a string), or there is a newline char. Thus, it will never match any string.

Actually, you do not need any lookarounds to get the substrings you need. Use the following regex with `RegexOptions.Multiline` option:

```
^\(([^()]+)\)
```

The `^` will make sure the match appears at the start of a string, `([^()]+)` will capture into Group 1 one or more chars other than `(` and `)`, and then `)` will get matched.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%28%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%29%5C%29&i=0%20-12.67%20Td%0D%0A%2FHelv%2014%20Tf%0D%0A%28Source%3A%20ABC%20%2F%20XYZA%29%20Tj%0D%0A0%20-15.624%20Td%0D%0A%28Job%20Source%20No.%3A%20GRQX%20ID%2027299%29%20Tj%0D%0A0%20-15.624%20Td&o=m), the results you need are in Group 1.

[image]

In C#, use the following code:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"^\(([^()]+)\)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```